# Utilizing makeArray values in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to create a listener that keeps track of the current slide number of a carousel, and then based on the slide number, adds a class to the corresponding navigation link to mark the link as active.

```
var menu = $("#menu a");
var menuIndex = $.makeArray(menu);

getCurrentSlide = function(){   
    var currentSlide = $("#story").slickCurrentSlide();
    var menuSlideIndex = menuIndex[currentSlide];
    console.log(menuSlideIndex, currentSlide);
}

left.on("click", function(){
    getCurrentSlide();
})
```

This returns the desired link based on the slide number, in the console, that I wish to add a class to.

When I attempt to add a class to menuSlideIndex, I get this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

What do I need to do to menuSlideIndex in order to add a class to it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the code that causes the error (always nice to *include* the problematic code), I'd guess you're calling:

```
menuSlideIndex.addClass('something');
```

which will fail, since `addClass()` is a method of jQuery objects, and `menuSlideIndex` is a plain old `a` element. To make the call work, give it a jQuery wrapper:

```
$(menuSlideIndex).addClass('something');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Paul! Sorry about the missing code. I'm new to coding and Stackoverflow, so I will be sure to remember this for next time. I appreciate your help and patience.